# Jquery flickering using display

Tags: jquery, hover, flicker

hello everyone i have an issue with flickering. I created a fiddle so you guys can help me. thanks!!!

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsQEn/1/)

JS-Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("img").mouseover(function(){
      $("img").css("display","none");
   });

   $("img").mouseout(function(){
      $("img").css("display","block");
   });
});
```

Comment: well the logic makes little sense, you hide the element when you hover it but at that point the mouseout triggers and shows it again, also the relevant code should be included here in the question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `display` you could try `opacity`. This doesn't remove the img but makes it transparent so it still receives mouse events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("img").mouseover(function(){
      $("img").css("opacity",0);
   });

   $("img").mouseout(function(){
      $("img").css("opacity",1);
   });
});
```

Comment: how about letting jquery handle it: .fadeTo(300,0) and .fadeTo(300,1)

Comment: @Michal No, jQuery does that automatically. That's actually the point of jQuery.

Comment: This is actually better suited for CSS. `img:hover { opacity: 0; }`

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux Absolutely true, but then you'd have to worry about browser compatibility issues, like Michal(who deleted his comment) said, since ie 7,8 don't support opacity.

Comment: Well, they do.. you just have to use the filter. `filter: alpha(opacity=0);`

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux Yes, sorry i wasn't clear. What i meant was that when using jQuery's css function it sets the browser specific properties like IE's `filter` automatically so you don't have to worry about it.